# 2 divs in one row with max-width

Tags: html, css

I have 2 divs I want to show in one line when browser resizes. On all screens it will show in one line, but now it breaks in second line when browser resizes.

**HTML**

```
<div class="navbar" id="navbar">
    <a href="#" class="logo">
        <img src="logo.png">
    </a>
    <div class="topnav-con">
        <div class="menu-top-menu-container">
            <ul class="nav-menu" id="menu-top-menu">
                <li><a href="#">nav 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">nav 2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>                                  
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.navbar {
    .max-width: 1310px;
}
.logo {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-right: 25px;
}
.topnav-con {
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #7A9CBD;
    clear: none;
    float: left;
    max-width: 1203px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Is the second `.` in `.navbar{.max-width: 1310px;}` a mistake or some sort of IE hack?

Comment: Its working fine... what are you looking for?

Comment: which two divs are you talking about?

Answer (score 2):

Don't keep the width of the .topnav-con as 100%.

Keep some ratio between both class `.topnav-con` and `.logo`

```
.logo{
    width: 20%;
}
.topnav-con{
    width: 80%;
}
```

But it's not preferable while displaying navbar. Keep the ratio till some `min-width: 600px`. 
Then break the menu into next line.